# PostgreSQL partition query by date optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, partitioning, database-partitioning

We have a table that has approximately one billion records per month. Considering 18 months of history we are talking about 18 billion records.

This table is partitioned weekly by date (so we have around 74 partitions).

For one of our queries we need to get the last 1000 records of one given unit. Something like this

```
  SELECT code, obs_time
    FROM unit_position 
   WHERE unit_id = 1
ORDER BY obs_time DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

The problem is that for this we have the following result in explain:

> Limit  (cost=96181.06..96181.09 rows=10 width=12)
>
> ->  Sort  (cost=96181.06..102157.96 rows=2390760 width=12)
>
> ```
> Sort Key: unit_position .obs_time
>
>  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..44517.60 rows=2390760 width=12)
>      ->  Append  (cost=0.00..44517.60 rows=2390760 width=12)
>
>      ->  Seq Scan on unit_position (cost=0.00..42336.00 rows=2273600 width=12)
>
>      ->  Seq Scan on unit_position_week350 unit_position (cost=0.00..21.60 rows=1160 width=12)
>
>      ->  ... (ALL OTHER PARTITIONS) ...
>
>      ->  Seq Scan on unit_position_week450 unit_position   (cost=0.00..21.60 rows=1160 width=12)
> ```

In the other hand if we get a query like this (limiting the query to the first interval where we can get the 1000 records) we can >2x faster results:

```
  SELECT fake, obs_time
    FROM unit_position 
   WHERE unit_id = 1
     AND obs_time >= NOW() - '7 weeks'::interval
ORDER BY obs_time DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

The question is, considering that we are ordering by obs_time, is there a way to make the query use the partitions and only search the first n partitions needed?

In most cases the results will be in the most recent 4 partitions (so it would only search those 4 partitions) and only in some very few it would have to search all the partitions.

If after getting n partitions (by order) it finds the 1000 results it won't consider the rest of the partitions (billions of records discarded). The tests/explain show that PostgreSQL is not doing this. It is actually going for all partitions (if it doesn't get WHERE state limiting the QUERY to the constrains of the PARTITIONS. Is there a way to force this? (for example in ORACLE one can give suggestion to the DB engine on how to perform some queries, even though I also don't know if do this for partitions)

The overhead of doing each on of the partitions manually (giving the intervals) get us worst results (and doing these we could actually be working without partitions, it would be better to have different tables).

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will dynamically query one week at a time up to the limit hopefully taking advantage of the partitioning. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bcd3b/1)

```
create or replace function unit_position_limited_by(l integer)
returns setof unit_position
language plpgsql as $function$

declare
    week timestamp := date_trunc('week', transaction_timestamp());
    total integer := 0;
    inserted integer;
    not_exists boolean;
begin
    loop
        return query execute $$
            select *
            from unit_position
            where
                unit_id = 1
                and obs_time >= $1 and obs_time < $2
            order by obs_time desc
            limit $3
        $$ using week, week + interval '1 week', l - total;
        get diagnostics inserted := row_count;
        total := total + inserted;
        exit when total = l; 
        if inserted = 0 then
            execute $$
                select not exists (
                    select 1
                    from unit_position
                    where obs_time < $1
                    )
            $$ into not_exists using week;
            exit when not_exists;
        end if;
        week := week - interval '1 week';
    end loop;
end; $function$;
```

To select from it:

```
select *
from unit_position_limited_by(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL's partitioning is a bit of a hack, and this is one of the areas that shows. There's no "smart partition scan" node type that can lock all partitions but only scan them in order until a rowcount requirement is satisfied.

Partitioning scan limiting is only done with `constraint_exclusion`, which requires that the query planner be able to prove from constants in the query that partitions will not be required.

A proper solution to your problem would require the addition of a new scan type in PostgreSQL where Pg took a lock on all the partitions when the query began but only scans them until it satisfies a rowcount requirement from an outer plan node.

You've already found one of the better workarounds available to you, adding a constant to limit which partitions are scanned. There is no query hint to limit the partitions scanned, though you *can* write an explicit plan yourself, like:

```
  SELECT code, obs_time
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM unit_position_week_350
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM unit_position_week_349
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM unit_position_week_348
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM unit_position_week_347
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM unit_position_week_346
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM unit_position_week_345
   ) unit_position_350_to_345
   WHERE unit_id = 1
ORDER BY obs_time DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

... but I haven't tested to see how this plans out and whether it performs decently. You might need to move the `ORDER BY` into the subquery or even the `unit_id` if the planner doesn't push that condition down its self.

Comment: In the end of my text (question) I already talk about this case. This was one of the things I had already tried and I actually got worst results (not a lot worst, but worst). 
In your answer, you have to do the full query anyway, because you have the ORDER BY in the main query. Like you said you need to have it by subquery, otherwise you have worst results.

Comment: @RGPT Unfortunately you don't really have any better options for this; as I said, partitioning is somewhat primitive in Pg and it has some downsides as well as upsides.